# Tracking links going to 404 pages

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, tracking

I have a price comparison website with quite a few tracking links like this:

```
<a href="/go.php?id=6000579" class="fh-price-go-link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer">ANCHOR</a>
```

Sometimes the shops I link to remove pages, causing my tracking link to return a 404 instead of leading to a working page.

When that happens, Google Search Results report `Not found (404)` errors.

Any ideas for fixing this, so Google becomes more happy? I thought have `nofollow noreferrer` would be enough, but it doesn't seem so...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I believe software like Screaming Frog SEO can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google is not going to help you identify bad links -- they just punish sites that have them. Neither the 404 kind or the bad neighborhood kind. It makes sense they don't help with the bad neighborhood kind as spammers could use that information ... But I don't know why they won't provide a page test for links to 404 pages.

The external links are something webmasters need to keep an eye on themselves. How they do it, manually or with the help of software is of no interest to Google. But having links to irrelevant content, Malware or other unwanted content, or 404 pages is bad for your site in the eyes of visitors and Google.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `noreferrer` has nothing to do with this.  Thats for the browser.

From [Using nofollow tags to support SEO](https://www.smartinsights.com/search-engine-optimisation-seo/link-building/what-is-a-google-nofollow-tag-and-why-should-i-care/)

> **A summary of what Google has to say on nofollow links**
> “In general, we don't follow them. This means that Google does not transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially, using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap. Also, it's important to note that other search engines may handle nofollow in slightly different ways.”

It doesn't say that won't try to open it.  I don't think you can do much about it.  And I don't think its an issue with it being in the GSE's report.